# Filtering a nested Object based on keys which match values in an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm having difficulties filtering keys of a nested Object based on another array, while retaining the original Object structure.

Input:

```
data = [
          {0: { key: "A", values: { 0: {g1: 0, g2: 0, g3: 0, g4: 0}}}},
          {1: { key: "B", values: { 0: {g2: 0, g3: 0, g5: 0}}}}
       ]

arr = [g1, g2, g3]
```

Expected Output:

```
data = [
          {0: { key: "A", values: { 0: {g1: 0, g2: 0, g3: 0}}}},
          {1: { key: "B", values: { 0: {g2: 0, g3: 0}}}}
       ]
```

What i have done so far:

```
data.forEach(function(e,i) {
    r = Object.keys(e[i].values[0]).filter(d => arr.includes(d))
    console.log(r)
})
```

This correctly prints [g1,g2,g3] and [g2,g3], but i want to retain the original Object structure, and not just have a list of the common keys.

Comment: It seems that you may be misrepresenting your `data` value. Are you sure it's not `[
          { key: "A", values: { 0: {g1: 0, g2: 0, g3: 0, g4: 0}}},
          { key: "B", values: { 0: {g2: 0, g3: 0, g5: 0}}}
       ]`? The structure you're showing us is a bit nonsensical, and doesn't match the code attempt you've shown us.

Comment: Does `data` really have two objects, one with a '0' key and one with a '1' key, or are you just showing the index of the array there? The same with `values` is values an array or really an object with a '0' key?

Comment: @JLRishe *"doesn't match the code attempt you've shown us"* - Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but the structure that OP has provided does indeed match the code attempt. Here it is copied and pasted from the question (I've added quotes to the array items): http://jsfiddle.net/g7dstuej/

Comment: @MarkMeyer Not to repeat myself here, but can't tag two people in a single comment. The code and output that OP has included in the question would only work if the `0` and `1` *are* actually keys, though I agree the structure is bizarre.

Comment: Thanks @TylerRoper -- we see so many arrays notated this way from console cut-n-paste, that I assumed it was wrong…should have looked closer.

Comment: @MarkMeyer No worries! I was scratching my head for a couple minutes myself. I find it hard to believe that it's simply coincidence that the format is identical to a console output - perhaps it was a "misinformed" attempt to recreate such a structure.

Comment: @TylerRoper Ok, thanks. I misunderstood what the `[i]` in OP's code was doing. Sure seems like a weird way to structure data, but it does indeed match the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would do the trick, assuming your `data` object is true to form (explanation is included as code comments).

```js
function pruneObject(object, desiredKeys) {
  Object.keys(object)
    .filter(key => !desiredKeys.includes(key))  //Ignore desired keys
    .forEach(key => delete object[key])         //Remove the leftovers
}

var data = [{ 0: { key: "A", values: { 0: { g1: 0, g2: 0, g3: 0, g4: 0 } } } }, { 1: { key: "B", values: { 0: { g2: 0, g3: 0, g5: 0 } } } } ];
var arr = ['g1', 'g2', 'g3'];

data.forEach((item,index) => pruneObject(item[index].values[0], arr)); //Prune each "values" object

console.log(data);
```

**Note:** This modifies the original object, although if necessary I could write an alternative solution to preserve it and return a new object instead.

Answer (score 0):

This code does what you want. Reduce the array `r` to an object and assign it to the original object.

```js
var data = [
          {0: { key: "A", values: { 0: {g1: 0, g2: 0, g3: 0, g4: 0}}}},
          {1: { key: "B", values: { 0: {g2: 0, g3: 0, g5: 0}}}}
       ]

var arr = ["g1", "g2", "g3"]


var output = data.map(function(e,i) {
    var r = Object.keys(e[i].values[0]).filter(d => arr.includes(d));
    var values = r.reduce((obj,key)=>{obj[key] = 0 ; return obj;},{});
    var obj = {};
    obj[i] = Object.assign(e[i],{values:{0:values}})
    console.log(obj);
    return obj;
})

console.log(output);
```

Actually it is not much better than rebuilding the output object from scratch

```js
var data = [
          {0: { key: "A", values: { 0: {g1: 0, g2: 0, g3: 0, g4: 0}}}},
          {1: { key: "B", values: { 0: {g2: 0, g3: 0, g5: 0}}}}
       ]

var arr = ["g1", "g2", "g3"]

var output = data.map(function(e,i) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[i] = {key : e[i].key, values : {0:{}}};
    arr.forEach((ele)=>{
      if(e[i].values[0][ele] != undefined)
      {
         obj[i].values[0][ele] = e[i].values[0][ele];
      }
    });
    
    console.log(obj);
    return obj;
})

console.log(output);
```